# Sorting of list containing dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list where its elements are dictionary in turn. I am trying to sort this list based on two keys. first key is a date field and second field is a type feild. the Type field order which i want is something like first type-a then then type b and then c.
I have a list which defines the ordering of type field.I want to sort by date and at the same time i want to sort the list of dictionaries according to the order given in ordering list.
Example:

```
Ordering = ['a','b','c']

list = [{'a': 1, 'date': '5-09-2018', 'type': 'b'},
        {'a': 2, 'date': '5-09-2018', 'type': 'a'},
        {'a': 6, 'date': '5-09-2018', 'type': 'c'}]
```

Now, here since the dates are same so I want it to be sorted in order of type a, b and then c.

```
final_list = [{'a': 1, 'date': '5-09-2018', 'type': 'a'},
              {'a': 2, 'date': '5-09-2018', 'type': 'b'},
              {'a': 6, 'date': '5-09-2018', 'type': 'c'}]
```

I want to use two keys , one for date and other for type.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Can you format your question properly? It's kind of hard to understand. You can do this by highlighting the stuff you want to show as code and pressing ctrl+k.

Comment: `5-09-2018` is a syntax error without quotes.

Comment: Your output can't be achieved by sorting. You start with a dict like `{'a': 1, 'type': b}`, but no such dict exists in the output. It looks like you've sorted only the `type` keys of all dicts. Is that some kind of mistake or is that really your desired output?

Comment: I think this will help you `sorted(list, key=lambda x: (x['date'], x['type']))`